# Posting JSON values without quotes not working with model binding in ASP.NET MVC Web Api OData controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm a bit perplexed by the behavior of my ODataController. I'm binding to an entity containing four properties - a nullable decimal, a string, a long and an array of longs. If any one of the values in the body of the POST request is missing quotes, the controller fails to bind to the entity.

This is a huge problem since I am using Json.NET on the client side, and it does not (at least by default) add quotes around decimals, ints, longs etc. Is this really the intended behavior of the OData model binding, or am I doing something wrong?

Works:

```
{"Amount":"70.0","Description":"some text","PayerId":"1","DebtorIds":["1", "2"]}
```

Does not work:

```
{"Amount":70.0,"Description":"some text","PayerId":1,"DebtorIds":[1,2]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2010/07/15/odata-decimal-and-json.aspx). It seems to be by design.

> To make sure that systems can round-trip data - read it and write it back without unintentional modifications - we were very careful about only using a numeric literal form for very simple common cases (16-bit and 32-bit signed values, to be precise).

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, I wrote a JsonConverter

```
internal class NumericConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private bool checkType(Type t)
    {
        return t == typeof (decimal) || t == typeof (double) || t == typeof (float);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            // We cannot pass null or the call will be ambiguous
            // ReSharper disable once ExpressionIsAlwaysNull
            writer.WriteValue(value);
            return;
        }

        var valuetype = value.GetType();
        var baseType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(valuetype);

        if (checkType(valuetype) || checkType(baseType))
            writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
        else
            throw new Exception("value type must be a numeric type");
    }

    private static object ToNullable(string s, Type t)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && s.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            var conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t);

            var convertFrom = conv.ConvertFromString(s);
            if (convertFrom != null) 
                return convertFrom;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None) return null;
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;

        var value = reader.Value.ToString();
        var baseType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType);

        if (value == string.Empty)
        {
            return baseType != null ? 
                null : 
                Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
        }

        if (baseType != null)
            return ToNullable(value, baseType);

        var conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(objectType);
        return conv.ConvertFromString(value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return checkType(objectType) || checkType(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType));
    }
}
```